# Dúvida para criar e trabalhar com array de classes em JAVA

Tags: java, funções, classes, método

Tenho um programa com 2 classes. A classe player que contem apenas o atributo nome:

```
public class player {
String name;
}
```

E tenho a classe Principal que tem a função abaixo e a chamada da mesma no main

```
Public class Principal{
public static void setPlayers(int valor){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<valor;i++){
            player[] vetor = new player[valor];
            vetor[i] = new player();
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Insira a quantidade de jogadores de 1 a 4");
    int n = 4;
}
}
```

Agora a dúvida, eu criei 4 players e quero colocar o nome deles ou pegar o nomes deles. Qual chamada devo fazer no main?
Tentei essa abaixo e fala que a vetor não existe

```
vetor[0].getName();
```

Para o exercício que estou fazendo, preciso armazenar uma quantidade X de jogadores e alterar/pegar seus nomes. Então precisei manipular os dados desse vetor

Comment: A classe `Principal` seria o jogo ? E porque não tem ela o vetor de jogadores ? Melhor seria até um `ArrayList<Player>` para ser fácil de gerir a quantidade de jogadores que tem. `vetor[0].getName();` não funciona pois você não tem nenhum método `getName` na classe `Player`.

Answer (score 4):

Você tem um problema de escopo do array `vetor`. Como ele foi criado dentro do `for`, ele só existirá enquanto o `for` estiver sendo executado e só poderá ser acessado aí também.

Jogando a linha `player[] vetor = new player[valor];` para fora do `for` resolve seu problema de acesso a ele.

Quanto a criar e manipular um `Player`, você precisa criar os métodos de acesso na classe `Player`. Do jeito que está hoje, sem um método `getNome()`, o compilador reclamará que esse método não existe:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Isso feito, você pode fazer assim dentro do `for` para criar e atribuir um nome a um `Player`:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.setName("Joaquim");
vetor[i] = player;
```

Para exibir o nome do jogador recém-criado, você poderia adicionar a linha a seguir no fim do `for`:

```
System.out.println(vetor[i].getNome());
```

*Cuidado com o nome da classe usando apenas letras minúsculas. Apesar de ser tecnicamente válido, não é boa prática em Java. Em vez de `player`, sua classe deve se chamar `Player`.